# What it mean the name Alexander Esam Abood in Chinese and what it is it’s calligraphy?

Tags: translation, meaning

I’m asking this question because, I’m really interested to know what does it mean that name in Chinese and how it is written in Chinese English, such as Cheng.

When I found [this](http://www.mandarintools.com/chinesename.html) site, I thought it is what I’m looking for, but it is not.

Alexander means protector of men.

Esam means the one who guard.

Abood means unity.

Alexander is taken from Alexander the Great and the last 2 names are taken from Arabic language.

So what is the calligraphy for Alexander Abood in Chinese and what does it mean Alexander Esam Abood in Chinese language? Because, in here I found that it means this, this and this, and I was thinking that in other languages it has different meanings to it.

I’ve tried also to find in Google about what’s the calligraphy for this full name and what does t mean in Chinese language, but the search has failed. I do not know where to look for the answer I’m looking for.

Comment: They're not Chinese words. Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @神秘德里克 I want to know what does it mean this full name I mentioned, and how it is written in Chinese. I mean not like   が？我乖乖喔 this, I want in English style where I can easily pronounce my name. Now it is clear? And in the same time to be a Chinese name while it is in English.

Comment: @神秘德里克  Names, words whatever it is.

Comment: Please use correct (or at least easy to understand ) language to describe your question. It doesn't have to be English or Chinese. Post it to other the-languague-you-use website will help you get answers more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chinese do not usually translate foreign names by their meanings, we transliterate them.

For example, we do not translate the name 'Armstrong' as '手臂(arms)强壮(strong)' ; we transliterate it as '阿姆斯特朗 (Āmǔsītèlǎng) in Mandarin and '岩士唐'(ngaam4 si6  tong4 )  in Cantonese

'Alexander Esam Abood' could be transliterated as 亚历山大 伊泌 亞甫戶 and the meanings of individual characters in this transliteration are irrelevant.

> Alexander means protector of men.
>
> Esam means the one who guard.
>
> Abood means unity.

If you know the origin meaning of the English name, you can just translate the origin meanings.

> "Alexander Esam Abood" means "the one who **guards**, **protects** and **unifies men"**
>
> "亚历山大 伊泌 亞甫戶" 的意思是 "**守护**，**保护**和**达成统一**的人"

Comment: In Chinese language does it have the same meaning my name? Or it has different meaning?

Comment: @Alex A Even each  individual characters  in 亚历山大 伊泌 亞甫戶 has meanings,  the whole name itself has  no meaning.  it is a  transliteration, not a translation